# Qual a diferença entre "estar", "está" ou "esta"?

Tags: ortografia, conjugações, ser-estar, adjectivos-demonstrativos

Como saber quando devo usar "estar", "está" ou "esta"? Qual a diferença?

Answer (score 5):

**Estar** é um verbo no infinitivo.

**Está** é a flexão do verbo “*estar*” na terceira pessoa do singular. (Ex: *Ela está doente*)

**Esta** é um pronome demonstrativo feminino e é usado para indicar algo no espaço. (Ex: *Esta menina é bonita*)

Comment: _Esta_ é tanto um pronome como um determinante (o exemplo dado associa-se ao determinante, até).

Comment: Vale ressaltar que "esta" é usado para algo que está mais próximo do orador.

Comment: Eu acrescentaria que frequentemente "estar" e "está" são pronunciados da mesma maneira ("está" ou "tá").

Comment: A resposta poderia ter mais exemplos

Comment: @Paulo Você fala português e está fazendo essa pregunta? Credo.